# SignalR reuse logic when pusing from the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, signalr

I'm trying to reuse the logic for my hub when pushing from the server.  I have a hub that looks like so:

```
public class NotesHub : Hub<INotesCallbacks>, INotesCalls
{
    public async Task AddNote(string note)
    {
        Note newNote = NotesService.Add(note);

        // All connected clients will receive this call
        await Clients.All.BroadcastNewNote(newNote);
    }
}
```

I have a web-api method that I want to use to push notes to my clients.  I'm aware I can do this from the web-socket but I would prefer to use a hybrid of rest and Websockets so I can just do server pushes currently.

My testing api method looks like so:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotesHub>();

    var note = "TestValue";
    Note newNote = NotesService.Add(note);
    context.Clients.All.BroadcastNewNote(newNote);
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

I know I could abstract the logic to another class, but I already have the logic in the NotesHub,  Is there a way I can just call my Notes hub method from my `IHubContext`?

Comment: Ok squash that. my idea fell flat on its face

Comment: I feel like there should be a way to cast it to something more typed but i haven’t see a way yet

Comment: I was going to suggest cast, that is what fell flat. :P

Comment: Yeah I guess I’ll have to add another class and interface

Comment: Yeah I am thinking the hub is doing too much. (mixing concerns). Have the hub for the single purpose of sending notifications and let it be the dependency of the service.

Comment: @Nkosi, Yeah I agree, I was modifying an example I found online for work, but the real issue is that I primarily only want my hubs for Server Side Execution.  I figured there would be a nice way of doing things but I'm going to abstract all of the logic so the hubs only take care of sending